# How to convert the name of Class into a string in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ruby-on-rails-3, class, typeconverter

I have a variable called `@class = Book`. `Book`being the constant representing the class.

I want to convert it to a string so i can use it in creating instant variable used in the views

In other words, i want the opposite method of `constantize` which can take a string and convert it into a class.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed ! I tried before but didn't work because i was using different variable in the view to check the value !! aarrrgghhh !!Lool !

Comment: You could post the solution so i could checked as the correct answer, in case somebody has the same question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get name of a class by calling its `name` method:

```
@class.name
```